# Can't deploy an app on the app store using Microsoft App Center

Tags: ios, react-native, build, version, visual-studio-app-center

Submitting a freshly build built with App Center used to work perfectly for us. But this week, it's not working at all. Every time we try to deploy, 
through `build > distribute > store`, we have the same message appearing in the bottom :

`Oh no! Build XX failed to distribute. Error: Release notes string or mandatory update boolean were successfully updated, but failed to distribute to some or all the destinations.`

[image: Oh no! Build XX failed to distribute. Error: Release notes string or mandatory update boolean were successfully updated, but failed to distribute to some or all the destinations.]

And we're stuck with that, we can still deploy the build, by downloading it, an doing it manually, but still, we kind of lost the need to use `Appcenter.ms`

Comment: I have same error on Android store distribution

Comment: On my side, I didn't have time to look how to resolve this issue, and I don't think my team have found anything yet .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCenter to automatic sign your builds, you might have lost your connection to the apple.developer portal.Go to settings and reestablish your connection. Maybe you also needs to agree to new terms with Apple on the apple.developer site.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work either. In the end, I got it to work again by simply recreating a new app on App Center.